# Convert date to unix format (PHP)

Tags: php

How to convert this date:

**Dec 09 2015, 00:21:58**

to unix timestamp format in PHP?

Comment: https://tinyurl.com/jobabtt

Answer (score 2):

You can use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class and [getTimestamp](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimestamp.php) method.

```
$date = new DateTime('Dec 09 2015, 00:21:58');
echo $date->getTimestamp();
```

or [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function.

```
strtotime('Dec 09 2015, 00:21:58')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function like this:

```
<?php
echo strtotime("Dec 09 2015, 00:21:58");
?>
```